# Gulp concat scripts and css in order to dev and prod

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I need differet tasks and commands to run for concat and uglify all css files to one and all script files to one (in appropriate order) for production and still have the single files for developers version.

Also i need watcher to dev files.

But for prod, i need only to add gulp commands to deployment script.
I don't understand how i can replace several files to one in html template.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style4.css">






<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script4.js"></script>
```